# Is There Synergy With Primal Savagery and Grappler?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack

The grappler feat states that

> You have advantage on attack rolls against a creature you are grappling.

And Primal Savagery states you

> Make a melee spell attack against one creature within 5 feet of you.

Which I interpret to mean you can have advantage on primal savagery attacks so long as you're grappling your target. Is that right?

Answer (score 12):

I don't know what you mean by "synergy", but if you're asking if the cantrip's attack roll is made with advantage, then the answer is yes. *All* attack rolls are made with advantage against a creature with you are grappling if you have the Grappler feat.